# Is their a better way to rewrite this SQL Query?

Tags: sql, t-sql

Good day, I have a query that utilizes a nested select to gather data from several tables... Is there a far better way to rewrite this query to speed up its process? The most time consuming part is the batch insert... hope you can help...

Comment: I assume that all the tables in the joins have the necessary indexes?

Comment: This is a job, not a question, and much more info about indexes et cetera would be required to answer it.  More constructively, I suggest you reduce the case as much as possible to remove extraneous factors that are no affecting the performance of the query.  You are more likely to get a good answer that way.

Comment: yes they are... @I.K.

Comment: ok, so they are indexed. Now what performance analysis have you done? what is the output of the query plans? why is that insert slow? table scans?

Comment: @bnieland query aside the simplest question behind this query is that is their a better way to extract the data from multiple tables aside from me using the nested select which consumes a lot of time...

Comment: @I.K. it returns 20,000 records and has multiple joins that is why it runs slow.. I wonder if I use another method aside from nested select it would be better..?

Comment: A JOIN can almost always replace a nested select and generally have better performance.

Comment: +1 for edit.  Did any of the answers help?

Comment: I think you need to show us your code for us to properly help you. Fo one thing, you may mean something completely different by nested select than I am interpreting. Are you using correlated subqueries or derived tables, for instance? 20,000 records is virtually nothing to sql server when it is properly indexed, so I would suepect you have written a poor query, but without seeing it, it is hard to say if thr problrm is that you are inadvertently running the equivalent of a cursor or if you have nonsargeable where clauses or one of a bunch of different possibilities.

Answer (score 1):

Here is what I would do assuming that your tables are indexed as you have said: I would rip out that select distinct statement and stick it into a separate SP, obviously the data will be in a temp table which is indexed. I would then call this SP from within a main proc and then join this temp table with the main insert statement. This will allow the optimiser to know the distribution of the data in the temp table and make some optimisations. Let me know if that was not clear. I use this technique all the time. It also results in easier to maintain and read code.

Answer (score 0):

Okay, given the givens, I think a good bet would be to use indexed views.  This allows alot to your joins and computations to be done at insert time and will seriously reduce the complexity of the actual insert SP.

see [http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd171921(v=sql.100).aspx](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd171921%28v=sql.100%29.aspx)